# i tried to add VGG16 layers to my model but it gives a value error

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

the error is like this

**Input 0 of layer conv2d_32 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 512]**

I tried many thing  but it does not work

here is my model

```
inp = Input(shape=(48,48,3))
vgg_layer = [VGG16(include_top=False, weights = "imagenet" ,pooling="max",input_shape = (48,48,3))]

m_layer = [(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')),
(BatchNormalization()),
(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2, 2))),
(Dropout(0.25)),
(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')),
(BatchNormalization()),
(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2, 2))),
(Dropout(0.25)),
(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')),
(BatchNormalization()),
(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2, 2))),
(Dropout(0.25)),
(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')),
(BatchNormalization()),
(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2, 2))),
(Dropout(0.5)),
(Flatten()),
(Dense(256, activation='relu')),
(BatchNormalization()),
(Dropout(0.25)),
(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))]


model = Sequential(vgg_layer  + m_layer)
```

Comment: what's your input shape?

Comment: (35887, 48, 48, 3) @NicolasGervais

Comment: dont use pooling when you instantiate vgg16, it'll work like that